# var functionName vs functionName assignment in a closure

Tags: javascript, function, closures, variable-declaration

This closure code would work:

```
function setupSomeGlobals(){
    var num = 666;
    gPrintNumber = function() { // play with var assignment 
        console.log(num)    
    }
    gIncreaseNumber = function() {
        num++;
    }
}

setupSomeGlobals();

gPrintNumber();
gIncreaseNumber();
gPrintNumber();
```

Yet, when I place the `var` keyword in front of the functions within the code, it all seems to not work. Why is that? Is `var` making these variable local only? Why would that matter?

```
function setupSomeGlobals(){
    var num = 666;
    var gPrintNumber = function() { // play with var assignment 
        console.log(num)    
    }
    var gIncreaseNumber = function() {
        num++;
    }
}

setupSomeGlobals();

gPrintNumber();  // ReferenceError: gPrintNumber is not defined
gIncreaseNumber(); 
gPrintNumber();
```

Comment: Missing `var` is a mistake, and it makes your variables implicit globals.

Comment: A mistake as in this isn't good practice? And what do you mean by 'implicit globals'?

Comment: "Is var making these variable local only?" Yes that is exactly what it is doing

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [What is the function of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/1529630)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is var making these variable local only?

Exactly. You can't access local variables from outside the `setupSomeGlobals` function.

Undeclared variables, i.e. without `var`, become global variables, which you should avoid as very bad practice. If you want to encapsulate some functions in a clean and safe way, try module pattern:

```
function setupSomeMethods() {
    var num = 666;
    return {
        gPrintNumber: function() {
            console.log(num)    
        },
        gIncreaseNumber: function() {
            num++;
        }
    };
}

var methods = setupSomeMethods();

methods.gPrintNumber();  // 666
methods.gIncreaseNumber(); 
methods.gPrintNumber();  // 667
```